# call/post mysql into tables

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to get it to look at the mysql rows and if the rows equal left then draw this table.

Blocks has the following:
`id`,`title`,`file`,`side`

---

```
$queryblocks = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blocks ORDER BY id") or die(mysql_error());
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($queryblocks)) {

//select blocks
$blocktitle = $data["title"];
$blockcontent = $data["file"];
$blockside = $data["side"];
}

if($blockside = "Left"){
//START LEFT BLOCKS
echo "<table bgcolor=\"#141414\" width=\"150\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" valign=\"left\">
<tr>
<td width=\"150\" height=\"22\" background=\"cpstyles/TeamofGoD/sidebar.gif\"><center><font color=\"#ffffff\">$blocktitle</font><center>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width=\"150\" background=\"cpstyles/TeamofGoD/block-bg.gif\"><center>$blockcontent</center>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width=\"150\"><center><img src=\"cpstyles/TeamofGoD/sidebar2.gif\"></center></td>
</tr>
</table><br>";
}
```

Comment: i can get it to post just one block, I just cant get it to continue posting all the blocks that have "Left" under colum side.

Comment: What about just moving your html code into the loop ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($queryblocks)) {

//select blocks
$blocktitle = $data["title"];
$blockcontent = $data["file"];
$blockside = $data["side"];

if($blockside = "Left"){
//START LEFT BLOCKS
echo "<table bgcolor=\"#141414\" width=\"150\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" valign=\"left\">
<tr>
<td width=\"150\" height=\"22\" background=\"cpstyles/TeamofGoD/sidebar.gif\"><center><font color=\"#ffffff\">$blocktitle</font><center>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width=\"150\" background=\"cpstyles/TeamofGoD/block-bg.gif\"><center>$blockcontent</center>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width=\"150\"><center><img src=\"cpstyles/TeamofGoD/sidebar2.gif\"></center></td>
</tr>
</table><br>";
}
}
```

Comment: I missed the last "}" when i pasted the code. It's in the loop already. I've gotten it to post everything, just can't get it to post only "Left" blocks.

Comment: I pretty much have this code twice, once for "Left" and once for "Right". As of right now it posts both "Left" and "Right" where it should only be posting "Left" or "Right".

Answer (score 0):

You need to put inside the while loop your conditions and table code.
Or you can just have a jump/goto section back and forth the conditions and the loop which is somewhat ugly.

Comment: found it
$queryblocks = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blocks ORDER BY id ASC") or die(mysql_error());
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($queryblocks)) {
if($data['side']=="Left"){
MY TABELS
 }
}

Comment: great then..
the code below by sankalp mishra works it just that the conditions must be "==" for equality or "===".